# How to check if all of dns resolvers are working?

Tags: dns

How can I check if all of dns resolvers are working under linux console?

Comment: Try to add a bit more detail to your question, does something not work ? How many have you configured ? Internal domains ? The two usual utilities are `dig` and `nslookup`

Comment: You should try nslookup

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of DNS resolvers from `/etc/resolv.conf`.  Here's a function to do that:

```
# print the IP addresses of all configured nameservers
resolvers() {
    awk '$1 == "nameserver" { print $2 }' /etc/resolv.conf
}
```

And usually you'd use `dig` or `host` to query a DNS resolver to see if it's working.  In this example, I'm testing whether we can resolve `NS` (nameserver) for google.com.  If you're relying on a specific host being resolvable, change `google.com in ns` to that hostname.

```
# given a nameserver IP address, exit successfully if it's responding, false otherwise
is_resolver_responding() {
    dig +short google.com in ns @$1 >/dev/null
}
```

Here's one way to put the functions together.  It prints the IP address of each nameserver, followed by `OK` or `BAD`.  You could easily change this to exit if one of them isn't working, or do whatever you need.

```
# print whether each configured resolver is responding (<ip> <"OK" or "BAD">)
for resolver in $(resolvers); do
    printf '%s is %s\n' "$resolver" $(is_resolver_responding $resolver && echo OK || echo BAD)
done
```